# Angular Load Json Error

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm an Angular beginner.
I want to load a `json` on load, this works well 
but if I make a change to an `input` field, I get an error message.

```
Error: $rootScope:infdig Infinite $digest Loop
```

Thanks

My HTML

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
<div id="wrapper">
    <header style="height:50px;"> </header>
    <div class="container">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/controller.js"></script>
        <section>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <label for="words">Wörter</label>
                <input ng-model="words" id="words" type="number" name="words" placeholder="Wörter" min="10" max="10000" value="{{words}}" step="10"> 
            </div>
            <p>{{words}}</p>
            <div id="view" class="col-md-6">

                <ul ng-controller="loadContent">
                    <li ng-repeat="content in contents | orderBy:random">{{content.text}}</li>

                </ul>
            </div>

        </section>
    </div>
</div>
```

My javascript

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('mainCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.words = 40;
    $scope.letterLimit = 400;
});
app.controller('loadContent', function ($scope, $http) {
 $scope.random = function () {
        return 0.5 - Math.random();
    }
 $scope.loadContent = function() {
     var def = $http.get('data.json').success(function(data) {
         $scope.contents = data;
     });
 }
 $scope.loadContent();
});
```

My json

```
[
{"text": "Lorem ipsum1", "date" : true},
{"text": "Lorem ipsum2", "data" : true},
{"text": "Lorem ipsum3", "data" : true}
]
```

Comment: Remove `$scope.loadContent();` from your controller and add it as `ng-init="loadContent"` in your view.

Comment: Its very strange, could you can put your json, and this json is well loaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that angular is continuously disgesting your controller as soon as you interact with the view, and is therefore executing `$scope.loadContent();` at the bottom of your controller repeatedly.

I assume you only wish for this to fire once? If so, remove the function call from your controller and modify your view as below.

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="mainCtrl" ng-init="loadContent">
```

With this, `$scope.loadContent` is only called once. if you wish to call it another way, or multiple times, please specify in your question.

Comment: You're welcome. Also consider adding `ng-cloak` to your body to stop the browser displaying uncompiled angular code whilst the JSON is being loaded. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak. Obviously, if your JSON is local, this is never really an issue...